# How do you set an app so that only iOS4 users can download it?

Tags: iphone, ios4, download, compatibility, ios3.0

I have an app that is released in the app store and can be used by 3.x and 4.x.  We compiled it using 
base SDK Latest 4.2, and deployment target 3.0.

But now we've added changes that are 4.0 required (i.e. this app WON'T work if you are using iOS3.x), but we don't want to tick off any users who have 3.x

If I set the deployment target to 4.0, will this PREVENT a user on iOS3.x from installing it, and thereby deleting their older but still working version?

The last thing we want is to do an update, and have a number of 3.x users get ticked because not only can't they use the app anymore, but they can't go back to the slightly older version.

Comment: yes, it will still show up in the app store, but won't let anyone with 3.x download it (will pop up a message saying this app requires OS 4.0 or whatever). so should be alright.

Answer (score 0):

Future downloaders can't be on 3.x
Current downloads will be not deleted, on 3.x, but cannot get future updates.

However, if a user updates their apps through iTunes, they may lose the app in question as iTunes applies the update, and won't sync it back to their device.

The latter case is an unavoidable bug, though.

Comment: Any idea if that's still a bug today?

Comment: The above still applies. However, the proportion of 3.x devices is so small nowadays, it is not something to worry about. Only first-generation devices have to stay on 3.x. The majority of iOS devices are now on a version of iOS4. In fact, the vast majority of devices are on iOS5 now.

Comment: I assume the same bug applies if I drop support for iOS4 and only support iOS5?  My worry is iOS4 users upgrading (either via device or iTunes) and not being able to continue using the old version of the app.

Comment: I think that it does still happen, although I haven't tested with the latest version of iTunes. However, it is likely still to happen as it is not really a 'bug'. iTunes doesn't know what devices you will connect to it, so it updates all apps regardless of any other factor.

Comment: Why do you want to support iOS5? If it is just for a few specific things, you can do if/else's to support the newer features, if on the newer OS. If it is for most of your app, and are worried about iOS4 devices (iPhone 3G and iPod touch 2G), you'll probably want to wait a bit.

Comment: I want to use the UIViewController containment functionality that's only available in iOS5.  It's also more work to test on both devices, which adds up to a lot for this hobby project.

Comment: In your case, then, I'd say go iOS5 exclusive.